# SQL Hourly Data

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below retrieves weather data from a MySql database, and groups this data in to an hourly format.

```
select hour(datetime) AS hour
     , avg(Temperature) as AVGT 
from Database.minute
WHERE DATETIME
      BETWEEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour)
         AND ((CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour))
group by hour
order by  (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (SELECT hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour)
```

Output is as follows:

```
hour    AVGT
19     11.730
20     11.970
21     11.970
22     11.760
23     11.660
0      11.700
1      11.830
2      12.370
3      12.770
4      12.840
5      12.840
6      12.540
7      12.500
8      12.030
9      12.100
10     12.300
11     12.060
12     11.090
13     10.920
14     10.920
15     10.820
16     10.760
17     10.690
18     10.560
```

The time is now 18:15. All of the above output is correct apart from the data gathered for hour '18'. Instead of getting the average value between 18:00 and 18:15, it just outputs the average at time 18:00. ie. ignoring data between 18:01 and 18:14.

How can I modify the above query to include data in the current hour (18:00 to Now)?

Thanks

Comment: I have always had small issues like that when using BETWEEN  ...  If it were me, I would use WHERE `'time' <= 'x' AND 'time' >= 'y'` format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simply try

```
SELECT Hour(datetime)   AS hour, 
       Avg(temperature) AS AVGT 
FROM   DATABASE.minute 
WHERE  datetime BETWEEN ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - 
                          INTERVAL 23 hour ) AND Now() 
GROUP  BY hour 
ORDER  BY ( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(Now())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour )
```

Comment: Please also summarize the difference(s) and reasoning.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ankur! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [@Ankur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366527) (your filter citerion should not filter records up to the current hour, but rather the current time), however your date/time operations are very strange:

1. You don't need a subquery `(SELECT Hour(NOW()))` to obtain `HOUR(NOW())`;
2. You can express `( Curdate() + INTERVAL (SELECT Hour(NOW())) hour - INTERVAL 23 hour )` more simply:

   ```
   CURDATE() + INTERVAL HOUR(NOW()) - 23 HOUR
   ```

   Or, in my view, more clearly:

   ```
   DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 23 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
   ```
3. Your `ORDER BY` clause is a constant and therefore achieves nothing: did you mean to order by `hour`?

Therefore:

```
SELECT   HOUR(datetime) AS hour,
         AVG(Temperature) AS AVGT
FROM     Database.minute
WHERE    datetime BETWEEN
               DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 23 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
           AND NOW()
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour
```

Comment: Totally agree, much better way

Comment: Thanks both of you. Given the detailed answer and reasoning of eggyal's answer, along with his suggestion, I'll mark this as my accepted answer. Cheers